# Cloud Foundry Change Buildpack from Command Line

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack, stackato

I have a Jenkins app running on Cloud Foundry for a POC.  Since it's Jenkins it uses a bound service for file persistence.

I had to make a change to the Java Buildpack and would like Jenkins to use the updated buildpack.

I could pull the source for Jenkins from GitHub and push it again with updated references to the new build pack in the `manifest.yml` file or via a command line option.  In theory, the bound file system service's state would remain intact.  However, I haven't validated this assumption and have concerns I might loose the state.

I've looked through the client CLI to see if there's a way to explicitly swap buildpacks without another `push`.  However, I didn't see anything.

Is anyone aware of a way to change the buildpack of an existing application without re-pushing it to Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I couldn't find anyway to swap the buildpack without a push.  I did discover that my bound file system service remained intact and didn't loose any work.

**Answer:** re-`push` to change the buildpack.